# Append() not appending updated variable to a list in R

Tags: r, loops, append, iteration, repeat

I have some R code which isn't working as expected.

I want a loop which adds 1 to the variable called 'loops' on each iteration. I then want the value of loops to be repeated a certain number of times and appended onto a list called 'loopNum' using append(). However, the code just seems to be appending '0' to the list, not the updated value of loops.

Any ideas greatly appreciated! The code is here:

```
loops <- 0
loopNum <- rep(loops, times = 50)

repeat {
  loops <- loops + 1
  print(loops)
  append(loopNum, rep(loops, times = 50))
  if (loops == 50){
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to assign, i.e., `loopNum <- append(loopNum, rep(loops, times = 4000))`

Comment: Apart from @Roland's suggestion, do you really need us to create vectors of 4000 repeated elements? SO examples should be *minimal* working examples, right?

Comment: Ah, so simple! Thanks so much @Roland
And yes, fair point RuiBarradas, I've amended the original post in case anyone else tries to run the code. Thanks both!